# Error while trying to pass NULL to a timestamp field

Tags: c#, oledb

I am trying to insert records into Access table from SQL Server table.

For each row in SQL Server table, I'm checking for a condition that if timestamp field is NULL, then insert NULL into corresponding Access field as well.

Pasting a small code snippet here:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dra)  //Each datarow in SQL Server table
{
    OleDbCommand accessCmdUpdate = new OleDbCommand("update xxx set xxxID=@0,xxxNotes=@2,xxxdatetime=@3 where xxxID=@1", AccessConnection);

    accessCmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@0", dr[0].ToString()));
    accessCmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@1", dr[1].ToString()));
    accessCmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@2", convertedText));
    if (dr[3] != System.DBNull.Value)
        accessCmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@3",OleDbType.DBTimeStamp,100,ParameterDirection.Input,true,(byte)(100),(byte)(0),"xxxdatetime",DataRowVersion.Current,Convert.ToDateTime(dr[3])));
    else
        accessCmdUpdate.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@3", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp, 100, ParameterDirection.Input, true, (byte)(100), (byte)(0), "xxxdatetime", DataRowVersion.Current, DBNull.Value));

    accessCmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

I have tried inserting DbNull.Value for @3 (DBTimeStamp) parameter. But it doesn't work. I get the following error:

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: **No value given for one or  more required parameters**.
Parameters @0 and @2 are inserted properly.

How do I pass NULL for DBTimeStamp field using OleDbParameter?

Comment: Please submit the structure of the table. Maybe it's a mandatory field?

Comment: Tha table structure is exactly same for both Access and SQL Server tables.
It is not a mandatory field, but I have to pass all the field values from SQL Server table.

Comment: Can you verify the value of `convertedText`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved in this forum

http://forums.asp.net/p/1729383/4637110.aspx/1?Re+Error+while+trying+to+pass+NULL+to+a+timestamp+field

Answer (score 1):

I think you should select allow nulls constrain from database table for that field where you got exception.

Otherwise you forgot to give value to any field in code and it hasn't allow nulls constrain.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the name of `table` and `fields` used in SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just stepped into this issue: 
 Its important to know that OLEDB Paramaters must be in order. No matter what names are used. 
Add the parameters to the command object exactly in that order that correspondend to the appereance in the SQL string.